# Display Date time in UK and US

Tags: c#, datetime

**Update**

I want to display a date time value in 24 hour format for **either UK or US** depending on its current culture, using generic way.

The code is below (NOT the actual code, it is for the question only):

```
    var dt = new DateTime(2011, 4, 15, 17, 50, 40);        
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-us")) + " "
        + dt.ToString("H:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-us")));
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("G", new CultureInfo("en-gb")));
```

Result below:

**4**/15/2011 17:50:40
15/04/2011 17:50:40

It displays ok.

Is there a better way to display the time without using "H:mm:ss". Please note that The G for US display PM, which is not what I want.

The month is 4 for US, rather than 04, is there a way to display it in **04**.
.

**Update**

Below is what I want, ideally using generic way:

US: 04/15/2011 17:50:40
UK: 15/04/2011 17:50:40

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 4, 15, 17, 50, 40);        
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyy H:mm:ss"));// US format
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyy H:mm:ss"));// UK format
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) from MSDN

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom display like this,

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString(@"MM/dd/yy HH\:mm\:ss"));
Console.ReadLine();
// Displays 05/20/12 17:08:37
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for US:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-us", true);
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
ci.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "";
ci.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "";
```

Now you can either set the current thread culture like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

And display the date like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("G"));
```

Or you can pass the culture as a parameter to the ToString method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("G", ci));
```

If you prefer the second method you can wrap the code above in a static method so you can call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("G", Cultures.EnUs));
```